# Would a container view be used for this? (Swift/iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, transition

I have a row of buttons in Storyboard. When the "More" button is clicked I want the row to change buttons but the "More" button to stay present. Right now I have two separate viewcontrollers set up. The container view tutorials I looked up seemed that they are best used when it's the same element appearing in multiple view controllers. When it should appear different, I don't see the difference between using that and viewcontrollers. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this?